# PhD at University X or PhD from University X

Tags: prepositions

I wish to present my education for a potential employer. If I had the chance to phrase a whole sentence, I would go for "I received my PhD from University X", as suggested in other answers to related questions. However, the information needs to be put in bullet point style. I am not sure about the correct preposition here. My thoughts:

- PhD at University X

or

- PhD from University X

Please not that this information is not connected to a date (as in "2012: PhD from University X"), merely the fact that I earned a PhD is listed.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The question answered in this link is explictly excluded in the text of my question.

Comment: It should almost certainly parallel other bullet points, and context is needed in your question. Neither preposition is '**in**correct, as expanded sentences using either are retrievable. << PhD (Cantab)>> is one option often seen.

Comment: I suspect that this is one of those questions that might be best answered with "ask your university, because they're all different", since different universities might adhere to different style guides.